# What is another alternative to `TextChanged` event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling

I am working in windows form and have a few `textboxes` on a form.

These textboxes from top to bottom are connected, so if the text changes in `textbox1`, then `txtbox2` and `txtbox3` have to comply, if something changes in `textbox2` then 3 has to comply;... and so on ... not going to bore you.

Now I was looking for an alternative, more efficient way of calling the `textchanged event` on the textboxes so it doesn't do everything everytime, even if one charater has changed....

Something like focus off textbox event ... or some other alternative .

This would be in vb.net and windows form.

Comment: Speaking from experience: skip the pain of dealing with all the combinations of blur/change/etc events and just validate on submit.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency when deal with the UI. I'd suggest hooking all the TextChanged events to one Sub (select them all in the IDE then add the event) and build a SELECT CASE based on the TextBox name. Note that if you send text to a textbox the TextChanged will fire again - might be good to have a flag that suspends processing while the code changes the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TextBox.LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event inherited from [`Control.LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx).

This event is fired when the control looses focus, like <kbd>Tab</kbd> or clicked on another control.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox1.LostFocus perhaps? Or enable validation on the controls.

Control focus event order:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

CausesValidation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx